# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1 - Simulator stuck on boot

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried running my App on Android O on the new Canary Build of Android Studio, but when I launch the Simulator it get's stuck at boot. It's been 20 mins now that is stuck.

This happens with both a Pixel XL and Nexus 5X preset.

It is working fine if I use API 25 (Nougat)

[image: Simulator stuck at boot]

**Has any of you experienced this problem and fixed it?**

Comment: Have you tried to launch the same emulator image in a Windows PC? I think it's too early to say for sure it's a bug in the new emulator or a problem with your configuration

Comment: Not yet but I'm going to in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that I did not update all the components in the SDK Manager. After updating all of them the emulator ran fine